# Php fill div external page code at NON regular interval

Tags: php, html, refresh, intervals

I want a main php page (index.php) to load an external page (test.php) at different interval.
I tried this code into the index.php page and it works but I need that after the first refresh the index.php could read the new $_SESSION['timeout'] value i set in the test.php page and then could load the test page at the timeout vale and so on.

I guess you understand what I mean.

Any suggestion?

Thank you all

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload = function()
        {

            $(function(){
                  $( "#PIP" ).load( "test.php" );
            });
        }
        setInterval(function(){
           $(function(){
              $('#PIP').load("./test.php", {VAR1:"foo",var2:"bar"});
           });
        },<?php print $_SESSION['timeout']*1000;?>);
```

Comment: That won't work as expected. Your timeout will be set when the page has loaded, and the script will be executed once every n seconds. If you want to change the interval, you will have to block the rest of the script from executing, but I'm afraid you can not change the interval.

Answer (score 0):

In `test.php` put this code somewhere:

```
<input type='hidden' id='session-interval' value='<?php print $_SESSION['timeout']*1000;?>' />
```

Then, in index.php do something like that:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#PIP").load("test.php", function afterResponse(resp, status, xhr) {            
      if(status === 'error') {
        // show/log error msg
        return;
      }
      doAgainAndAgain();
    });
  });
}

function doAgainAndAgain() {

  var refreshInterval = $('#session-interval').val();

  var dataToPost = { VAR1: "foo", var2: "bar" };

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#PIP').load("./test.php", dataToPost, 
        function afterResponse(resp, status, xhr) {
          if(status === 'error') {
            // show/log error msg
            return;
          }
          doAgainAndAgain();
        });
  }, refreshInterval);

}
```

Comment: It does not work. It loops. What i need is refreshing that div at different interval. When it refreshed it must read the session var containing the value of the next refresh interval. Maybe I'm wrong with this approch, can you suggest something else?

Comment: @robolo previous code was incorrect. Please see edited version. $.load needs callback to determine when is loading done, or is or not request success. see: [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)